# Change install location in code behind with custom UI code

Tags: xaml, installation, wix, wix3.6

I am merging our installer projects from VS 2008 to VS 2012 and subsequently from the basic Windows Installers to Wix installers. I've created a standard Wix installer project which outputs a MSI that does all I want.

Now I've created a custom UI in WPF/XAML (Win 8 style) and a bootstrapper project that installs our projects using our own UI. The basics work just fine, i.e. installing and uninstalling.

I want to let the user change the install directory and the install scope (per user or per machine) through an 'advanced' panel. I can capture the settings in code behind, but I am unable to pass these parameters to my installer.

My directory tree is defined as follows:

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
  <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
     <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='$(var.ProductName)  $(var.CustomerAcronym) v$(var.Version)'>
        <Component Id='MainService' Guid="5E68A5A7-E9B3-4156-B84C-E8D7AA3DCBCC">
```

Any tips on how to handle this, so how to pass the user-defined path and scope to the Wix installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your UI, set the install path in a bootstrapper string variable, something like:

```
BootstrapperApplication.Engine.StringVariables["INSTALLPATH"] = "C:\somePath\someDir";
```

Then in your bundle.wxs, pass the string variable in as a property, something like:

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="MyPackage.msi" Id="MyPackage">
    <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLDIR" Value="[INSTALLPATH]" />
</MsiPackage>
```

UPDATE

If directory path contains symbols **[** and **]**, Engine resolves this part of the path as variable:

```
BootstrapperApplication.Engine.StringVariables["INSTALLPATH"] = "C:\[somePath]\someDir";
```

In this case, variable [somePath] doesn't exist in Wix Bundle, so INSTALLPATH will be "C:\someDir"

If you assing directory path from UI, it's better to **Escape** variable:

```
string directoryPathFromUser = "C:\[somePath]\someDir";
BootstrapperApplication.Engine.StringVariables["INSTALLPATH"] = 
    BootstrapperApplication.Engine.EscapeString(directoryPathFromUser);
```

Comment: Thanks! so simple yet i couldn't find it anywhere. I guess the same method will work for the scope (install all users vs. install this user)?

Comment: I think so, but you would have to make sure that in your installer, you specifically set the ALLUSERS property to the value you want, instead of setting the InstallScope attribute of the <package> element.